# Finding the product of 2 functions with modulus

Tags: functions, cryptography

Iam using an Affine Cipher that uses a product cipher to encrypt a message. I know the 2 functions/key.

$fa(x) = 3x + 5$ $mod(26)$

$fb(x) = 5x + 7$ $mod(26)$

I need to find the products of these functions. 
I am familiar with multiplying two functions.

$ ab(x) = fa(x) * f(b) $

**PROBLEM**

However, I have never multiple two functions with a particular modulus before. Can I ignore the modulus as they are both the same?

So thus it will be 
$ab(x) = (3x + 5) * (5x + 7) = 15x^2 + 46x + 35$

Then I will add the modulus 26, making it :

$15x^2 + 46x + 35$  $mod(26) $

Comment: That looks fine. You may also want to simplify 46 = 20 and 35 = 9

Comment: I think you're meant to use the composition of the two maps (so one after the other), so $f_a(f_b(x))$ or the other way round. Product ciphers are about compositions, not products as numbers.